# Configure Python custom logger from a config file without config the root logger

Tags: python, logging

I'm configuring a custom logger using the `fileConfig` function like this:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(config_file_fullname, defaults={"log_directory": log_directory})
self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
self.logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(self.logger, {})
```

This is quite simple and lets me set all the logger config using a file.
The problem is that this sets the root logger config and other librarys that use it's own logger gets also this config, causing errors in it's logger (in my case the requests lib raises a KeyError).

Is there any way to use a fileConfig-like function to load the configuration ONLY for my custom logger?
Or is there any way to reset the root logger config?

Comment: This sound like the way logging is use in your project is not how it should be. Libraries shouldn't have their own logging configuration or you will end up with problems like yours.

Comment: If I import the requests library before initializing my custom logger the problem dissapears because of the fileConfig function default argument disable_existing_loggers=True . But if the requests import is done after the initialization gets the KeyError.